# PHP Folder Array with parent ID

Tags: php, arrays, directory-structure

I am trying to list all the folders (only) in a directory and assign them an ID and a parent ID and the path of the folder using php and resulting in the format of 
(folderID, "folderName", parentID, path)

So far I have found a function that will list all the folders in a multidimensional array as follows:

```
function listFolders($dir)
{
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $return = array();

    foreach ($dh as $folder) {
        if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $folder)) {
                $return[] = array($folder => listFolders($dir . '/' . $folder));
            } else {
                $return[] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

This returns an array similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => New file.txt
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [level2] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [level2a] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [level2b] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [level1a] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Then I run that through another function:

```
$i = 0;
    $j = 1;

    function recursive_foreach($array) 
    {
        global $i, $j ;

        $out = '';
        foreach($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            if (!is_numeric($key))
            {           
                $out .=  "($j,\"$key\",$i,\"\")<br />";
                $j++;
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if(is_array($value)) 
            {
                $out .= recursive_foreach($value);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Which will return an output similar to:

```
(1,"level1",0,"")
(2,"level2",0,"")
(3,"level3",0,"")
(4,"level2a",2,"")
(5,"level2b",4,"")
(6,"level1a",8,"")
```

Which is close to what I need, but I'm having trouble with the parent ID. The output that I need is:

```
(1,"level1",0,"path")
(2,"level2",1,"path")
(3,"level3",2,"path")
(4,"level2a",1,"path")
(5,"level2b",1,"path")
(6,"level1a",0,"path")
```

where each level has the correct parent id and the path of the folder.

I've run out of ideas/knowledge as to how I can achieve this. Can anyone help me out please?